# Como puedo hacer mi Update mas optimizado en c# con sqlserver, se traba la instancia después de un tiempo porque el servidor no responde

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una migración de historias clínicas de una instancia de sql de un portátil a un servidor central. Se filtra con un rango de fechas, pero cuando son mas a menos unos 400 filas, toda la instancia se cae y responde el timeout del c# que ya lo tengo por 3 minutos. No lo puedo alargar mas por motivos de respuesta.

[image: Proceso de la instancia]

Se queda ahi por los 3 minutos de timeout y no responde hasta que pare el proceso.

Adjunto mi consulta de actualización

Debajo de la actualización se ejecutan mas funciones, que tambíen hacen peticiones.

Las funciones que se ven en el codigo *ValidarFechaNula y ValidarHoraNula* Pues es casi claro lo que hacen. Devuelven un convert(DateTime,fecha,102) y uno para la hora.

Las que llevan $ al principio ya traen la coma en lo que devuelve la función

```
        private string ValidarFechaNula(string Fecha)
    {
        string ValidarFecha = null;

        ValidarFecha = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Fecha) ? "null" + "," : "CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "',102),";

        return ValidarFecha;
}
```

La función SQLUPDATE HACE LO SIGUIENTE

```
        public static bool SQLUpdate(string sqlString, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        try
        {

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conexionSQL))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);

                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                }

                sqlConnection.Open();

                command.CommandTimeout = 300;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Utils.Titulo01 = "Control de errores de ejecución";
            Utils.Informa = "Lo siento pero se ha presentado un error" + "\r";
            Utils.Informa += "en la funcion SQLUpdate" + "\r";
            Utils.Informa += "Error: " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace;
            MessageBox.Show(Utils.Informa, Utils.Titulo01, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            MessageBox.Show(sqlString);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Conexion.sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) Conexion.sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Insert Completo

```
Utils.SqlDatos = "UPDATE [DACONEXTSQL].[dbo].[Datos atencion de la consulta] SET " +
"Dxprinc = '" + TabHistoCli["Dxprinc"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxEntra = '" + TabHistoCli["DxEntra"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxMuer = '" + TabHistoCli["DxMuer"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxRelac01 = '" + TabHistoCli["DxRelac01"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxRelac02 = '" + TabHistoCli["DxRelac02"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxRelac03 = '" + TabHistoCli["DxRelac03"].ToString() + "'," +
"DxRelac04 = '" + TabHistoCli["DxRelac04"].ToString() + "'," +
"ImpeDX = '" + TabHistoCli["ImpeDX"].ToString() + "'," +
"TipoDxPrin = '" + TabHistoCli["TipoDxPrin"].ToString() + "'," +
"UnidadEdad = '" + TabHistoCli["UnidadEdad"].ToString() + "'," +
"ValorEdad = '" + TabHistoCli["ValorEdad"].ToString() + "'," +
"EdadMeses = '" + TabHistoCli["EdadMeses"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodMediIngresa = '" + TabHistoCli["CodMediIngresa"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodiMedi = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiMedi"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodEspeci = '" + TabHistoCli["CodEspeci"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodiMediSalida = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiMediSalida"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodEspeciSalida = '" + TabHistoCli["CodEspeciSalida"].ToString() + "'," +
"FormAten = '" + TabHistoCli["FormAten"].ToString() + "'," +
"ImagAten = '" + TabHistoCli["ImagAten"].ToString() + "'," +
"LaboAten = '" + TabHistoCli["LaboAten"].ToString() + "'," +
"ProAten = '" + TabHistoCli["ProAten"].ToString() + "'," +
"TuvoControl = '" + TabHistoCli["TuvoControl"].ToString() + "'," +
"TipoControl = '" + TabHistoCli["TipoControl"].ToString() + "'," +
"TuvoProcedimiento = '" + TabHistoCli["TuvoProcedimiento"].ToString() + "'," +
$"Fechallega = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["Fechallega"].ToString())}" +
$"HoraLlega = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["HoraLlega"].ToString())}" +
"CodEstado = '" + TabHistoCli["CodEstado"].ToString() + "'," +
"MedioLlegada = '" + TabHistoCli["MedioLlegada"].ToString() + "'," +
"CualMedio = '" + TabHistoCli["CualMedio"].ToString() + "'," +
"NomAcomp = '" + TabHistoCli["NomAcomp"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodParen = '" + TabHistoCli["CodParen"].ToString() + "'," +
"DirParen = '" + TabHistoCli["DirParen"].ToString() + "'," +
"TelParen = '" + TabHistoCli["TelParen"].ToString() + "'," +
 $"FechaOcurre = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["FechaOcurre"].ToString())}" +
$"HoraOcurre = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["HoraOcurre"].ToString())}" +
"CausaBase = '" + TabHistoCli["CausaBase"].ToString() + "'," +
"SitOcurre = '" + TabHistoCli["SitOcurre"].ToString() + "'," +
"MotConsul = '" + TabHistoCli["MotConsul"].ToString().Replace("'", "") + "'," +
"HistEnfActual = '" + TabHistoCli["HistEnfActual"].ToString() + "'," +
"TensionSisto = '" + TabHistoCli["TensionSisto"].ToString() + "'," +
"TensionDiasto = '" + TabHistoCli["TensionDiasto"].ToString() + "'," +
"FrecuCardi = '" + TabHistoCli["FrecuCardi"].ToString() + "'," +
"FrecuRespi = '" + TabHistoCli["FrecuRespi"].ToString() + "'," +
"temperatura = '" + TabHistoCli["temperatura"].ToString() + "'," +
"PesoAMB = '" + TabHistoCli["PesoAMB"].ToString() + "'," +
"TallaAMB = '" + TabHistoCli["TallaAMB"].ToString() + "'," +
"IMC = '" + TabHistoCli["IMC"].ToString() + "'," +
"CatIMC = '" + TabHistoCli["CatIMC"].ToString() + "'," +
"PerimetroCefalico = '" + TabHistoCli["PerimetroCefalico"].ToString() + "'," +
"SPO2 = '" + TabHistoCli["SPO2"].ToString() + "'," +
"CabezaCuello = '" + TabHistoCli["CabezaCuello"].ToString() + "'," +
"Endocrino = '" + TabHistoCli["Endocrino"].ToString() + "'," +
"CardioPulmonar = '" + TabHistoCli["CardioPulmonar"].ToString() + "'," +
"Cardiovascular = '" + TabHistoCli["Cardiovascular"].ToString() + "'," +
"Abdomen = '" + TabHistoCli["Abdomen"].ToString() + "'," +
"GenitoUrinario = '" + TabHistoCli["GenitoUrinario"].ToString() + "'," +
"Neurologico = '" + TabHistoCli["Neurologico"].ToString() + "'," +
"Extremidades = '" + TabHistoCli["Extremidades"].ToString() + "'," +
"PielyFaneras = '" + TabHistoCli["PielyFaneras"].ToString() + "'," +
"OsteoMuscu = '" + TabHistoCli["OsteoMuscu"].ToString() + "'," +
"GlasGow = '" + TabHistoCli["GlasGow"].ToString() + "'," +
"Glaswog01 = '" + TabHistoCli["Glaswog01"].ToString() + "'," +
"Glaswog02 = '" + TabHistoCli["Glaswog02"].ToString() + "'," +
"Glaswog03 = '" + TabHistoCli["Glaswog03"].ToString() + "'," +
"EstadoGral = '" + TabHistoCli["EstadoGral"].ToString() + "'," +
"CabezaCuelloFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["CabezaCuelloFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"OcularFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["OcularFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"ORLFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["ORLFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"DorsalLumbarFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["DorsalLumbarFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"AbdomenFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["AbdomenFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"ExtremidadesFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["ExtremidadesFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"ToraxFisico = '" + TabHistoCli["ToraxFisico"].ToString() + "'," +
"CardioVascuFisi = '" + TabHistoCli["CardioVascuFisi"].ToString() + "'," +
"PielSub = '" + TabHistoCli["PielSub"].ToString() + "'," +
"ExaGineco = '" + TabHistoCli["ExaGineco"].ToString() + "'," +
"TactoRectal = '" + TabHistoCli["TactoRectal"].ToString() + "'," +
"ExaMamas = '" + TabHistoCli["ExaMamas"].ToString() + "'," +
"AparLocomo = '" + TabHistoCli["AparLocomo"].ToString() + "'," +
"AparGanglio = '" + TabHistoCli["AparGanglio"].ToString() + "'," +
"NeuroFisico = '" + TabHistoCli["NeuroFisico"].ToString() + "'," +
"pqsiquiatrico = '" + TabHistoCli["pqsiquiatrico"].ToString() + "'," +
"Conducta = '" + TabHistoCli["Conducta"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodiColumna = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiColumna"].ToString() + "'," +
"PosTPlan = '" + TabHistoCli["PosTPlan"].ToString() + "'," +
"Remision = '" + TabHistoCli["Remision"].ToString() + "'," +
"RemiNum = '" + TabHistoCli["RemiNum"].ToString() + "'," +
"DestinoUsuario = '" + TabHistoCli["DestinoUsuario"].ToString() + "'," +
"Activa = '" + TabHistoCli["Activa"].ToString() + "'," +
"ActivaInicialUrgencias = '" + TabHistoCli["ActivaInicialUrgencias"].ToString() + "'," +
"ExamenesAuxiliares = '" + TabHistoCli["ExamenesAuxiliares"].ToString() + "'," +
"EpicrisisActiva = '" + TabHistoCli["EpicrisisActiva"].ToString() + "'," +
"EpicrisisCerr = '" + TabHistoCli["EpicrisisCerr"].ToString() + "'," +
"ValoraH = '" + TabHistoCli["ValoraH"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodiMediValor = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiMediValor"].ToString() + "'," +
$"FechaValora = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["FechaValora"].ToString())}" +
$"HoraLlegaValora = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["HoraLlegaValora"].ToString())}" +
"DetalleValora = '" + TabHistoCli["DetalleValora"].ToString() + "'," +
"Soporte = '" + TabHistoCli["Soporte"].ToString() + "'," +
"OtAnteceCE = '" + TabHistoCli["OtAnteceCE"].ToString() + "'," +
"IngresoEPI = '" + TabHistoCli["IngresoEPI"].ToString() + "'," +
"EvolucionEPI = '" + TabHistoCli["EvolucionEPI"].ToString() + "'," +
"EgresoEPI = '" + TabHistoCli["EgresoEPI"].ToString() + "'," +
"CodiMediEpi = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiMediEpi"].ToString() + "'," +
$"FechaEpi = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["FechaEpi"].ToString())}" +
$"HoraEpi = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["HoraEpi"].ToString())}" +
"CodColor = '" + TabHistoCli["CodColor"].ToString() + "'," +
"NumeroCitas = '" + TabHistoCli["NumeroCitas"].ToString() + "'," +
$"Horaregis = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["Horaregis"].ToString())}" +
$"HoraAtencion = {Conexion.ValidarHoraNula(TabHistoCli["HoraAtencion"].ToString())}" +
"CodiRegis = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiRegis"].ToString() + "'," +
$"FecRegis = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["FecRegis"].ToString())}" +
"CodiModi = '" + TabHistoCli["CodiModi"].ToString() + "'," +
$"FecModi = {ValidarFechaNula(TabHistoCli["FecModi"].ToString())}" +

"ResumenEvoEPI = '" + TabHistoCli["ResumenEvoEPI"].ToString() + "'," +
"PrefiHis = '" + TabHistoCli["PrefiHis"].ToString() + "' " +
"WHERE CodConExt = '" + CodBusAten + "'";


bool Act = Conexion.SQLUpdate(Utils.SqlDatos);
```

Esta haciendo una migración de datos de un portatil a un servidor central.

Por lo tanto tengo que recorrer un ciclo de la tabla de la instancia del portatil, para verificar cuales ya están en el servidor, para saber cuales se deben ingresar y cuales actualizar.

```
SqlHistoCli = "SELECT * FROM [DACONEXTSQL].[dbo].[Datos atencion de la consulta] ";
SqlHistoCli += "WHERE ([Datos atencion de la consulta].PrefiHis = N'" + PfiPor + "') AND";
SqlHistoCli += "([Datos atencion de la consulta].Activa = 'False' ) AND ";
SqlHistoCli += "([Datos atencion de la consulta].FecAtenc >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + FecIniPro + "', 102)) AND";
SqlHistoCli += "([Datos atencion de la consulta].FecAtenc <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + FecFinPro + "', 102))";

ConectarPortatil();

SqlDataReader TabHistoCli;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.conexionSQL))
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SqlHistoCli, connection);
   command.Connection.Open();
   TabHistoCli = command.ExecuteReader();


   if(TabHistoCli.HasRows == false)
   {
       Utils.Informa = "Lo siento pero en el rango de fecha" + "\r";
       Utils.Informa += "digitado no existen datos para exportar, " + "\r";
       Utils.Informa += "atenciones de consultas.";
       MessageBox.Show(Utils.Informa, Utils.Titulo01, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       SqlDataReader TabHistorCen;

       while (TabHistoCli.Read())
       {
           ConectarCentral();
           // 'Revisamos si el número de codigo de atencion existe

           CodBusAten = TabHistoCli["CodConExt"].ToString();
           HistoPaci = TabHistoCli["HistoriaNum"].ToString();

           SqlHistCen = "SELECT * FROM [DACONEXTSQL].[dbo].[Datos atencion de la consulta] ";
           SqlHistCen += "Where CodConExt = '" + CodBusAten + "'";
           
           using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(Conexion.conexionSQL))
           {
               SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(SqlHistCen, connection2);
               command2.Connection.Open();
               TabHistorCen = command2.ExecuteReader();


               //Aqui Inserta la consulta si no se encuentra en el servidor central
               //Aqui la actualiza si ya se encuentra en el servidor central

              

           }//using

           TabHistorCen.Close();

       }//While
```

Comment: habria que ver que hace SQLUpdate como para que tarde tanto tiempo....

Comment: Como primer apunte despues de revisar el update, todas las lineas que empiezan con un ´$´ no terminan con una coma `,`. Como segundo apunte, las fechas en SQL server, si las pasas como string tienen que ir entre comillas simples, cosa que tampoco haces en el update. Mira de arreglar esto que te comento y como dice gbianchi, pon el codigo de la función SQLUpdate para poder ver que hace.

Comment: Ya añadí la función SQLUPDATE

Comment: agrega tambien el lugar desde donde lo invocas, el problema posiblemente es que estas invocando el metodo SQLUPDATE desde un ciclo for, lo que causa que en cada vuelta inicie la cree la conexion , la inicie se autentifica, hace la actualizacion m y la cierra.

Comment: mira lo primero que te veo es que abres y cierras la conexión muchísimas veces eso te alenta el método, segundo creo que es mas cómodo trabajar con listas de objetos, tercero se me ocurren  que podrías hacer es enviar toda la lista al servidor y insertar los datos desde un procedimiento almacendo  algo así : https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/ puedes usar la funcion marge de mssql para evitar duplicados

Comment: Creo que la respuesta de @EmmanuelGarciaValdez es la correcta. Enviar toda la lista y hacer un [Merge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). También estoy de acuerdo con su diagnóstico acerca de la lentitud. El proceso de abrir, autenticarse y cerrar la conexión es demasiado "cara" para estarla haciendo dentro de un ciclo. Es un gran **no-no**.